# calculate fields in data.json based on 1 day in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here I have an example of a case in the project I'm working on.

I have data like this => https://run.mocky.io/v3/1e7e5b56-1ae7-4212-92a1-1b233707f495

then, I want to console it with output like this =>

***("On `@timestamp` there were 12x api hits based on data.message")***.

so the question is, ***how do you calculate the @timestamp to be 1 day and calculate the total data.message in 1 day based on the @timestamp?***

Thank you very much in advance, I really appreciate all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would work:

```
const count = {};

yourData.forEach(item => {
  const currentDateate = getDate(item['@timestamp']);
  if (!count[currentDateate]) {
    count[currentDateate] = 0;
  }
  count[currentDateate]++;
});

console.log(count)
```

Where the `getDate` function would be a function that converts timestamp to date. And `yourData` would be the inner array in your "data", something like like `data[1]`